# Can a main breaker box be bonded at the meter box?

Tags: electrical-panel

[image]
[image: the meter box with ground rod][image: picture of the panel]

Im trying to add a subpanel to my main breaker box, I know that on a subpanel neutral bus and ground must not be bonded, but looking inside the main panel I don't see where the neutral and ground bars are bonded, also this panel does not have connection to a ground rod, the ground rod connection it's coming out of the meter box, Its this ok? can the neutral to ground bonding be inside the meter box? , thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: How is the service panel fed from the meter (cable, metal conduit, plastic conduit, etc.)? Can you provide a photo of the service panel with the cover off, and a photo of the meter?

Comment: Somebody bent the crap out of the PVC on the left of the panel, they bent a 90° with no radius. That is not code. There are no supports on any of your conduits. That is a code violation. It wouldn't surprise me to find it is not properly bonded given these violations.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the neutral can be bonded at the meter.  National Electrical Code 250.24(A)(1).

Here's a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/wyPTtN6QjzQ) where [Mike Holt](https://www.mikeholt.com) discusses this topic.

Comment: Is there any way to know for sure if its bonded inside the meter box? what could happen if I just bond neutral and ground on main panel? can this be dangerous if is really already bonded at the meter?

Comment: Yes, open the meter and look (though you'll likely have to have the utility open it). If you're installing a new panel, I'm not sure why you're worried about the service neutral bonding?

Answer (score 0):

If the neutral and ground are bonded at the meter (and it kind of looks that way, given that conduit down from the meter box is possibly protecting a grounding electrode conductor to a grounding rod), then there should still be a ground conductor from the main panel to the meter box (or the service disconnect, given there doesn't appear to be a service disconnect breaker in the panel in the picture), and bonded to the ground there. Perhaps it really is present and the picture just doesn't show this part of the panel, but if it isn't, I would venture that there is a deficiency here.

Comment: Double bonding can create ground loops which can cause problems, especially with audio and RF applications.